# How to draw tikz figures side by side, while using a loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, plot, loops

Right now I have some code like this:

```
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=0:2,rotate=-90] (\x, { 
    (sin(pi*\x r)* sin(pi*\x r) + 
    sin(pi/2*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r) + 
    2*sin(pi*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r)*cos(3*t)
}) [dashed];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

The final cosine term has a `t` in it, which I would like to iterate over, so I can draw about a half dozen of these with different values for `t`.

However, I would also like to set these figures side by side, equally spaced, so there are about a dozen of them in `\textwidth`.

When I try to do it manually without a loop, I get the figures on top of each other:

[image]

Below is complete code for the second picture:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=0:2,rotate=-90] (\x, { (sin(pi*\x r)* sin(pi*\x r) + sin(pi/2*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r) + 2*sin(pi*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r)*cos(3*1) }) [dashed];
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}
 %
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=0:2,rotate=-90] (\x, { (sin(pi*\x r)* sin(pi*\x r) + sin(pi/2*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r) + 2*sin(pi*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r)*cos(3*23) }) [dashed];
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should show a ts document that shows the problem If you do one minipage after theother they will come side by side enless you are doing something very odd, note however you are making 1cm wide minipages with `\begin{minipage}{1cm}` but your tikz plots look wider than 1cm.

Comment: Is `t` to be incremented by some fixed integer value from one plot to the next?

Comment: It could be an integer value, but best probably would be a full 2pi radians...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it(I could be wrong), you just want one drawing consisting of several curves - so simply just only make one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\n}{6}
\foreach \t in {1,...,\n}
\draw[dashed, xshift={\textwidth*(\t-1)/\n}] plot[domain=0:2,rotate=-90] (\x, { (sin(pi*\x r)* sin(pi*\x r) + sin(pi/2*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r) + 2*sin(pi*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r)*cos(10*\t) });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Six dashed curves]

Edit: non-overlapping

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\n}{6}
\foreach \t in {1,...,\n}
\draw[dashed, xshift={\textwidth*(\t-1)/\n}, xscale=0.6] plot[domain=0:2,rotate=-90] (\x, { (sin(pi*\x r)* sin(pi*\x r) + sin(pi/2*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r) + 2*sin(pi*\x r)*sin(pi/2*\x r)*cos(10*\t) });
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dashed separated curves]

Comment: This is nice, but why are they overlapping? I would like them to each exist in their own box. I suppose I could increase the xshift to fix this though...

Comment: @Wapiti Because they overlap in your question?